# Android Studio dart analysis_options.yaml file

Tags: android-studio, dart, static, analysis

We have a large Flutter app in which we are using an outside party's charting package that produces many unused variables hints in Android Studio Dart Analysis window.

Project structure: `flutter_app_root/contrib/charts/charts_common`.

I placed a **analysis_options.yaml** file in the flutter_app_root directory per:
*Excluding code from analysis*:
[https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#disabling-individual-rules]
and tried:

```
exclude:
    - "contrib/**"
    - "contrib/charts/**"
    - "contrib/charts/charts_common/**"
```

Each setting individually and together as well as placing a **analysis_options.yaml** file in each of the chart directories but no combination I can find will stop the static analysts from running on the code that is not ours.

Am I missing something?
Is there a log somewhere that can help debug?
Thanks

Comment: Find the directories you want to avoid indexing in the project view. Right Click > `Mark Directory As` > `Excluded` should prevent it from being indexed

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  This works awesome but it appears to be a user preference somewhere.  Is there somewhere I can do this for my entire team in a version control checkin so I don't have to show everyone how to do it and new people we bring on as well and new machine configs just "happen"?

Comment: I'd imagine so. I am not sure off the top of my head how though.